# basic Javascript array of objects syntax question

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects in Javascript. Can I change the object values like this.

- `query` ~ the array
- `propertyIndex` ~ a value that is the index of the array element
- `selected` ~ one of the variables of the object that is saved to the array
- `true` ~ the value I want to set selected to be equal to

Code:

```
 query[propertyIndex].selected='true';
```

Comment: No reason, expect I thought that was causing a bug, I'l' change it back in my code.

Comment: Just a quibble - "selected" isnt' a variable, it's a property. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

What went wrong when you tried it?

Comment: Well my code wasn't working, and I was wondering if this was legal or not. I assumed it must be but couldn't find the answer on Google.